# $wpdb->update return 500 error in response - Wordpress Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create an update user detail system inside wp-admin, request is getting send properly with all data as I checked inside developers tools (network), but response is getting received 500 in red color

```
public function edit_employee_data()
    {
        
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'employee', array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'dob' => $_POST['dob'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'joining_date' => $_POST['joining_date'],
            'address' => $_POST['address'],
            'salary_package' => $_POST['salary_package'],
            'gender' => $_POST['gender'],
            'marital_status' => $_POST['marital_status'],
            'department' => $_POST['department'],
            'designation' => $_POST['designation']
        ));
        
    }

add_action('wp_ajax_update_employee', array($this, 'edit_employee_data'));
```

Javascript used for Ajax call:

```
<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('form.edit_employee').on('submit', function(e) {
                        
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var name = $('#name').val();
                        var email = $('#email').val();
                        var dob = $('#dob').val();
                        var joining_date = $('#joining_date').val();
                        var address = $('#address').val();
                        var salary_package = $('#salary_package').val();
                        var gender = $('#gender').val();
                        var marital_status = $('#marital_status').val();
                        var department = $('#department').val();
                        var designation = $('#designation').val();
                        var message = $('.message').val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: ajaxurl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                action: 'update_employee',
                                name: name,
                                email: email,
                                message: message,
                                dob: dob,
                                joining_date: joining_date,
                                address: address,
                                salary_package: salary_package,
                                gender: gender,
                                marital_status: marital_status,
                                department: department,
                                designation: designation,
                                message: message,
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                $(".success_msg").css("display", "block");
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                $(".error_msg").css("display", "block");
                            }
                        });
                        
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

values are getting send properly with the action name but I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` operations need `WHERE` clauses unless you really intend to update all the rows in the table (unlikely in your example). `$wpdb->update()` has a third argument giving the `WHERE` filter, but you omitted it.

Figure out how you identify the row--the employee--you want to update. It might be by `employee_id`, for example.

Then provide something like this as the third arg.

```
[employee_id => $_POST[employee_id]]
```